# Doxygen in c# can't give reference link to reference class if uses "using"

Tags: c#, doxygen

I'm using doxygen to generate document,
when I using class full path (`Common.Enum.Enum.ServiceType`) to reference a parameter:

```
public void method(Common.Enum.Enum.ServiceType type){}
```

I can get hyperlink in the Property(`Common.Enum.Enum.ServiceType`).

If I use `using common.Enum.Enum`, and use:

```
public void method(ServiceType type){}
```

the document doesn't give hyperlink to my ServiceType property.

I want the second code style can get hyperlink to my return class,
thanks for any help

Comment: Please share some code to clarify your question.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question, thanks